# redirect_to with HTTP header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

Not sure if this is possible or makes any sense, but I'm trying to make a redirect after setting a HTTP header field. Something like:

```
request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
redirect_to url
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as `request` is the current request, not the redirect. Is there any way to call `redirect_to` with custom HTTP headers?

Answer (score 6):

It's **impossible** to redirect to a page with custom headers set, no matter what language or framework you use. In other words, there's no way to trigger an HTTP redirect and cause the client (browser) to add a custom header.

As you yourself mentioned, you're setting the custom headers for the response which is instructing the browser to redirect, not for the redirect itself.

The only way for a site to instruct a browser to issue an HTTP request with a custom header is to use Javascript and the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [response object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object) ...

> If you want to set custom headers for a response then response.headers
>   is the place to do it. The headers attribute is a hash which maps
>   header names to their values, and Rails will set some of them
>   automatically. If you want to add or change a header, just assign it
>   to response.headers this way:
>
> `response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"`

Comment: I tried this but the headers are not set in the redirected request. I added `redirect_to url` after this line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but there's an indirect way to do it

> redirect_to your_url, flash: { accept_header: 'application/json' }

and then check flash[:accept_header] in the target url.

This isn't particularly elegant, but it works. Its analogous to using a special url parameter -- your_url(accept_header: json) -- but its not going to be seen by the user/bookmarked/etc.

Comment: This looks like a *perfect* solution. Unfortunately, something is very badly wrong with this brand new app I've set up. I think I know why there are no headers. Printing the flash to the log only yields this:  ```#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007fb86c11a978 @discard=#<Set: {"alert"}>, @flashes={"alert"=>"You must first log in."}, @now=nil>
```

Comment: The problem is, I have disabled all ```before_actions```. I can't understand what about Rails 4.2 is trying to check for authentication on an application that I have left wide open. It's just crazy. I have searched for the string "You must first log in", and it literally appears out of thin air. If I could figure out what is happening before it gets to my page, then I would have the answer on why everything is getting stripped out of my request. It's a real mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I face with the problem too. Have two ways to do that.

1. In rails controller

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        # Change headers
        headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'

        # Require to redirect
        headers['Location'] = url
        render html: "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{url}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>".html_safe, status: 301
      end
    end
```

2. Or change .htacess of Apache or Nginx

```
  # Apache
  RewriteEngine On
  <Location "/somewhere">
    RewriteCond ...
    Header always set Accept "application/json"
    RewriteRule ...
  </Location>
```