# How do I add a token to my request in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

I have an upload application that will be accessible by multiple other applications. I want user security from those applications to be federated to this upload hub. I'm doing it with HTTP tokens that are shared between the applications.

I have read 5 different articles on how to secure an API in Rails. I have everything set up properly in the upload hub app. I have keys set up in my `User` table, and I have shared this key with the user table in the other apps. I have the code in place to check for this key, and to locate the appropriate subscription. Upon failure, the user is redirected to the login page of the source application.

There's just one thing. I can't find *anywhere* how to create the actual request! I want the users in the other applications to click an "upload" link that will take them to this application. No problem creating the link, of course. The problem is, how do I add the token to the request?

See, I'm not making programmatic requests to an API... The user is actually going from one app to another. I want the upload hub app to check the request and say "Oh, there's this big long key. Let me see if I can find a user associated with that. I'm obviously not going to put it in a query string.

The *only* thing I've come up with on my own is to have a bit of `jQuery` code that constructs a form with a hidden item containing the key in it, which it would get from a hidden field on the current page, then do a `POST` against the upload hub app. That's not really a token, but it's doable. Surely there's a better way?

***UPDATE***
I went the jQuery "postGo" route where I construct a form with a hidden field and send it as a parameter to the other app. I had forgotten about `protect_from_forgery` though. However, even after turning protect_from_forgery off, Rails somehow still strips all parameters except for `controller` and `action` from outside requests. Undocumented feature? Or maybe I missed the documentation.

Really, I just want SSO on a couple of apps. It looks like I'm going to have to create an Oath provider. Sure are a lot of hoops to jump through to federate a simple session on some apps that I own.

Comment: you can use custom headers to do that? if so make use of the `request` object. when redirecting a user to other app set the appropriate value in headers, have a look at [redirect_to with HTTP header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504931/redirect-to-with-http-header)

Comment: How about having your app make a request to the upload hub in the backend and have the hub return a token, then your app trigger the redirect? The token can be provided to the client in the redirect response which use it as a query string so your upload hub can check against it (store it in redis).

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with `strong parameters`. [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). Take a look at your logs and try to find something like: `Unpermitted parameters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible way of doing this.

1. In the upload controller method of the app, instead of redirecting the user directly, make a request to the upload hub app.
2. In the upload hub app, add a controller method and generate a token, store it and a user's credential in redis, or other storage of your choice, then response the app with the token.
3. Your app's upload controller method receive the response from upload hub, then give 302 response back to the client, with the token included in the redirect url.
4. The client redirects to the upload hub
5. The upload hub router accepts this format, the token can be in a query string.
6. Check in redis and find it by the token and match the user's credential